# Squid Proxy Multiple Ports based different outgoing address configuration not working

Tags: proxy, configuration, squid

I have squid Configuration in ubuntu 20 with multiple listening ports and each port has different outgoing address assigned by using "tcp_outgoing_address" directive. but In Ubuntu my configuration is not working some how. even in any linux distro it's not working. it works fine with squid for Windows with same config file.
please find sample config for one port as below.

```
acl proxy4011 myportname 4011 src 0.0.0.0/0 
http_access allow proxy4011 
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.11.100 proxy4011
http_port 192.168.1.192:4011 name=4011
```

Same kind of rules added for some more ports and acl also.

So my question is is there anything on Linux side that is stopping the squid to send the traffic through different nic for each port or I am missing anything in squid Configuration side? I have disabled the firewall and also enable ipv4 forwarding from sysctl file. Is there any default network security in linux that is affecting the squid to perform this operation?

If anyone need to check my full conf file I can paste here.

Comment: why not running multiple instances instead a single configuration?

Comment: I tried already. even on single port configuration traffic can not be sent through the specified address. if traffic is somehow blocked for traveling from one interface to another even single port configuration will not work. I have single address for accepting request with multiple ports and each port has assigned different out going interface.